# Creating seamless low poly terrain tiles

Tags: vertices

I'm scratching my head trying to create a seamless tiling system for low poly terrain;

I want to align every vertices of the border to the neighbor terrain; how can I 'easily' achieve that ?

Thanks !

[image: illustration]

Comment: Shift-Alt select each edge border and use "Bridge Edge Loop". This should connect the 2 borders. Maybe add 1 other loop cut afterwards to make the squares evenly distributed.

Comment: By seamless, do you mean that they should tile only on the x-axis or should they be truly seamless in all directions? If the latter is the case, are we talking about one plane that should get repeated?

Comment: @abel that made it seamless ! but afterwards when I cut and repeat the seam is still there

Comment: @metaphor_set only in the x (or y) axis; it's for an infinite runner game

Comment: So you actually need many different tiles that are tiling seamlessly together. Ok, got it.

Comment: @metaphor_set that is correct ! do you have a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not... entirely. The problem is that I can make the tiles seamless on the geometry side, by using "Bridge Edge Loop" without any problem. The seams that you see, are produced by the edge normals, because they "change direction" even then, when all vertices are at the same level. If that's still ok for you and you can solve that programmatically, I'd write an answer.

Comment: @metaphor_set well, keeping in mind that i'm a n00b when it comes to programming in python .. why not, if you can explain from a beginner level :)